# How to store a .wav file in Windows 10 with NAudio

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, naudio

I'm trying to store my 16000hz 16bit mono PCM audio bytes to a wav file in a Windows 10 app.

NAudio normaly has a WavFileWriter, but it seems to be gone in the Windows 10 version. I can only seem to find access to new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1); from https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/1.7.3/

Is there a stream I can use to create the Wav file or its bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that NAudio removed *WavFileWriter* because there's now a substitute in the standard UWP API, in the *Windows.Media.Audio* namespace.
What you should use now is something like this:

```
MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
```

Documentation for the api: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs)

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into AudioGraph but i couldn't find a way to set 16000hz anywhere (when saving audio). Then I found NAudio that looked promising. Any suggestions how to save a 16khz wav?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason `WaveFileWriter` is not available in UWP is because you can't use the old `File` APIs in UWP so `WaveFileWriter` would need to be re-written to work in UWP.

As Tommaso has pointed out, UWP does actually have the ability to create WAV files using `AudioGraph` but it's options are very limited, so you may not be able to specify the exact sample rate you want. You might find that `AudioEncodingQuality.Low` uses a lower sample rate with WAV. (I can't remember off the top of my head)